# Carregar páginas da base de dados

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Como faço para carregar páginas do banco de dados, de modo que as diretivas do AngularJS funcionem?

Atualmente, estou carregando as páginas com jQuery. A página carrega perfeitamente. Acontece que, quando isso ocorre, o ciclo de inicialização do AngularJS já foi finalizado e ele não reconhece as diretivas que vieram com a página carregada da base de dados.

Answer (score 0):

É necessário usar o serviço $compile. A resposta desse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database) tem um [exemplo](http://plnkr.co/edit/F91xvGHBASvqCGBJcEYY?p=preview) no plunker como isso funciona.